# Windows 8 "Device Setup" process stuck without further progress

Tags: windows-8, usb, installation, drivers

After plugging-in of an USB device, standard window with progress bar appears. The problem I experience is that it gets stuck at certain progress and doesn't continue no matter how long I wait.

Screenshot:

[image]

I can imagine that the process scans database of available device ID's for the one currently added. It should be simple linear process which should finish sooner or later. So how it could get stuck and how to fix it?

**Additional details:**

The problem is here with both **USB2** and **USB3** port. [The device](http://www.trust.com/en/all-products/15146-compact-vibration-feedback-steering-wheel-gm3200) ships with no installation CD, it is generic one. Latest supported Windows is *Windows 7*, but this shouldn't be the reason why database scan hangs... From the device I need only foot switches (pedals) to emulate hotkeys on the keyboard which actually [already works](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/RemapJoystick.htm) for me even if driver installation is not finished. But my question is about hanging of the device scanning process what is annoying. Do you have any experience in this area?