# Windows 8 "device setup" screen takes forever

Tags: usb, windows-8.1

When I plug in a USB device (flash driver and USB to serial adapter) I see the same screen as the user in this question [Windows 8 "Device Setup" process stuck without further progress](https://superuser.com/q/809667/213319), but I'm not getting stuck it's just very long.

When I plug a new USB memory stick / flash drive it is recognized and appears in explorer but the progress bar of the device setup is only at about 30% at that point and will take 20 or 30 more seconds to complete.

Same thing when I plug a USB to serial adapter. Drivers are installed, it appears in device manager, but the device setup screen only completes 20 or 30 seconds later.

What is happening ? Is this a know issue in Windows 8 ?

Answer (score 0):

It's most likley that the computer knows your mouse is plugged in, but it's still looking for drivers. Sometimes it may take over 30 seconds to find the correct drivers.